# Finder sort order not alphabetical (again)

Tags: macos, finder, high-sierra, sort

I know you might be annoyed by those questions, but here is my specific problem:

A list of PDFs, which is in no explaineable way ordered non-alphabetical. It is consistent between list and column view. Does anyone see the logic behind this or knows a fix?

The naming pattern is `Konto_cccccccc_Auszug_20XX_NNN.PDF` where `cccccccc` is the account number, `XX` is the corresponding year, and `NNN` is the number of the statement, padded with leading zeros. The visible part is `Konto_ccc` and `XX_NNN.PDF`. All statements are from the same account (thus have the same number).

As visible in the image, the last two statements from 2017 are at the top. This happens with no other 10th and 11th statement though. Also 2018_001 is at the top, below the last 2017 statements (wich is correct, relatively).

[image: account statements list]

Comment: To eliminate typos, have you tried copy/pasting the name from 16_010 to 17_010 then just changing the 6 to a 7?

Comment: The names are actually autogenerated by my bank... But you were right: Someone at the bank thought: Let´s just change the naming scheme :D How could customers ever struggle with this. The change was going from `Konto_cccccccc-Auszug_20XX_NNN.PDF` to `Konto_cccccccc_Auszug-20XX_NNN.PDF`
Thank you very much to remind me of that easy way to test!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an easy fix... The naming scheme of my bank actually changed, from `Konto_cccccccc-Auszug_20XX_NNN.PDF` to `Konto_cccccccc_Auszug-20XX_NNN.PDF`, which is kind of invisible to the human eye. Thanks for @Tetsujin for the recommendation to eliminate typos by copying one name to another!

Comment: If your bank has made a permanent change to the file name from "-Auszug\_" to "\_Auszug-", you could select all items, right click, and select "Rename X items..." to find and replace "-Auszug\_" to "\_Auszug-" to keep everything sorted in a single folder.

Comment: Yes thank you, that´s exactly what I have done :) I just had not realized the change in the first place...